# ¿Cómo convertir un long a su representación textual sin pasar por un String en java?

Tags: java

Buenas tardes.

Mi pregunta es algo que no he visto por ningún lado. Estoy intentando convertir una variable de tipo `long` a un `byte[]` en java, conteniendo ese `array` una representación textual del valor integral, pero sin utilizar la clase `String`. Es decir, debería tener el mismo comportamiento que el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
long valorOriginal = 23L;
byte[] objetivo = ((Long) valorOriginal).toString().getBytes();
```

Sin embargo, en principio no debería utilizar la clase `String` ya que es para un módulo de seguridad para mi aplicación, y he leído que no es buena práctica almacenar algo que se va a encriptar (o hacer algún `hash` sobre él) en un `String`, ya que con un `byte[]` tenemos control absoluto de la variable y la podemos limpiar después de su uso, obteniendo algo como lo siguiente:

```
long valorOriginal = 23L;
byte[] objetivo = MiClase.toStrBytes();  // Necesito esta funcionalidad
byte[] hash = MiClase.hash(objetivo);  // Hash (no recuperable)
MiClase.limpiar(objetivo);  // sobre escribe el array con bytes nulos
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: [`Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()), con enfásis en el **`new byte array`**. Además, el `String` de tu ejemplo deja de estar accesible justo después de la llamada a `getBytes()`, ¿qué importa si alguien pudiera (que no puede) cambiar el valor?

Comment: Lo que decis de la lectura de la memoria (cosa que ya de por si es complicada) del string, cae en bolsa de saco roto. A menos que me haya perdido algo, un Byte es byte que guardaria el numero (de 0 a 9) en un byte.. con lo cual, seria facil de leer igualmente si supieras la posicion de memoria...

Comment: Entiendo la razón de no querer un `String`. ¿Pero realmente es necesario que los bytes que obtienes equivalgan a la representación *textual* del número? No es suficiente con simplemente obtener los 8 bytes que componen un long? Es mucho más sencillo. Y si de todas maneras le vas a aplicar un hash no recuperable, ¿realmente importa que uses un método u otro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes manipular cada byte sin pasar por cadena (String) de la siguiente forma. Dejo los System.outs para que veas los que pasa en cada línea.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (byte b : longToBtyeArray(0x7000000000008005L)) {
            System.out.printf(" %02X", b);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] longToBtyeArray(final Long l) {
        int numeroDeBytes = Long.BYTES;
        System.out.printf("Número de bytes en un Long: %d\n", numeroDeBytes);
        byte[] arregloDeBytes = new byte[numeroDeBytes];
        System.out.printf("Número en base Decimal: %d\n", l);
        System.out.printf("Número en base Hexadecimal: $%08X\n", l);
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroDeBytes; i++) {
            byte b = (byte) ((l >>> i * 8) & 0xFF);
            System.out.printf("Byte %d: %02X\n", i, b);
            arregloDeBytes[i] = b;
        }
        return arregloDeBytes;
    }
}
```

En ésta línea está lo más importante:

`byte b = (byte) ((l >>> i * 8) & 0xFF);`

En pocas palabras, desplaza cada byte del Long y 'filtra' cada byte con un operador and.

El código produce la siguiente salida:

```
Número de bytes en un Long: 8
Número en base Decimal: 8070450532247961605
Número en base Hexadecimal: $7000000000008005

Byte 0: 05
Byte 1: 80
Byte 2: 00
Byte 3: 00
Byte 4: 00
Byte 5: 00
Byte 6: 00
Byte 7: 70

 05 80 00 00 00 00 00 70
```